# Woher kommt das Wort „Sprachmuskel“?

Tags: etymology, speaking

Im Wörterbuch von Jacob & Wilhelm Grimm steht nichts weiter als

> sprachmuskel, m.: nach Strickers studien über die sprachvorstellungen
>    (Wien 1880) sind unsere sprachmuskeln auch beim stillen lesen
>    beschäftigt. Minor zeitschr. f. österr. gymn. 47, 580.

Doch ich bin mir sicher, dass ich dieses Wort schon zig Male gehört habe, immer im Zusammenhang mit Sprachenlernen, „den Sprachmuskel trainieren“.

Comment: Es gibt einen Muskel für die Spannungsregelung der Stimmfalte, der auch "Sprachmuskel" genannt wird http://www.iatrum.de/musculus/m-vocalis-Sprachmuskel.html

Comment: Manche trainieren den Sprachmuskel, andere den Gössermuskel.

Comment: @chirlu: Von wo bist du? Ich hätte bisher vermutet, dass man das Bier, das in Göss (ein Stadtteil von Leoben) gebraut wird, nur innerhalb Österreichs kennt.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Ist vermutlich auch so, aber manchmal schnappt man auch was aus dem Ausland auf. ;-) Ich bin aus dem Rhein-Neckar-Raum (Mannheim/Heidelberg).

Comment: Ehrlich gesagt verstehe ich die Frage nicht. Vor allen Dingen unter dem Gesichtspunkt, dass du die Antwort von Hubert akzeptiert hast. Diese ist eine Erklärung dessen, was der Sprachmuskel ist, aber nicht, woher das Wort kommt. Und beim Wort handelt es sich um eine schlichte Komposition von "Sprache" und "Muskel". Und genauso wie "Laufschuhe" Schuhe zum Laufen sind, so ist der "Sprachmuskel" der Muskel zum sprechen.

Comment: Ich dachte 'Sprachmuskel' bezieht sich auf etwas Abstraktes, womit, wenn wir ihn trainieren (indem wir diese Sprache einfach nur sprechen) uns die Sprache viel vertrauter vorkommt und wir somit "leichter" ohne gross zu überlegen reden können. Dem ist offensichtlich nicht der Fall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Der Sprachmuskel (Musculus vocalis) ist ein Muskel der inneren Kehlkopf-Muskulatur. Ohne diesen Muskel ist keine Stimmproduktion möglich, also weder Sprechen noch Singen.

Der Sprachmuskel entspring der hinteren Fläche des Schildknorpels. Das andere Ende befindet sich beim Stellknorpel. Impulse aus dem Nervus laryngeus inferior (rückläufiger Kehlkopfnerv, auch Stimmnerv) führen zu einer Kontraktion des Sprachmuskels, wodurch die Stimmlippen gespannt werden, und die Stimmritze verschlossen wird. Luft, die dann aus der Lunge in den Rachen gepresst wird, zwängt die Stimmlippen auseinander, jedoch schließen sie sich aufgrund ihrer Spannung sofort wieder. Dieser Vorgang wiederholt sich einige hundert Mal pro Sekunde, was zu einer Schwingung der Luft führt, die deutlich hörbar ist.

Eine Vielzahl von Muskeln in der Mund- und Rachenhöhle verformt diesen akustischen Resonanzraum, so dass im raschen Wechsel unterschiedliche Frequenzen verstärkt und gedämpft werden können, die allesamt dazu beitragen, dass aus dem Ur-Ton aus dem Kehlkopf verständliche Sprache oder Gesang werden kann.

Der Sprachmuskel ist nicht der einzige Muskel, der die Stimmritze verschließen kann. Das geschieht durch mehrere verschiedene Muskeln im Kehlkopf, der Sprachmuskel ist einer davon. Die Produktion von Tönen ist auch nicht die einzige Aufgabe dieser Muskel-Gruppe. Überlebenswichtig sind diese Muskeln bei allen Tieren, bei denen sich der Atemweg und der obere Verdauungstrakt kreuzen, also auch beim Menschen. Denn durch den Verschluss der Stimmritze und dem gleichzeitigen Schließen des Kehldeckels wird beim Schlucken verhindert, dass Speisen und Getränke in die Lunge gelangen. Aus diesem Grund kann man auch nicht sprechen während man schluckt.